# Get bit set position from unsigned integer

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a flag from a PDF that returns an integer of 4096.  According to [this website converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_unsigned_int.html?decimal=052048057054), I should be able to test the 13th position and get a positive result back using the function below but it's only giving a positive result back for position 12?  Is the position zero based or something so I would need to check the (pos - 1)?

```
bool GetIsBitSet(int flags, int pos)
{
    return (flags & (1 << pos)) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the position parameter in your function is zero based. That's due to the way the test is implemented which essentially sets up a mask by shifting 1 left `pos` number of times (which is equivalent to multiplying by 2 `pos` number of times).

```
 1 << 0   = 1     // tests bit 1   binary: 0000 0000 0000 0001
 1 << 1   = 2     // tests bit 2,  binary: 0000 0000 0000 0010
 1 << 2   = 4     // tests bit 3,  binary: 0000 0000 0000 0100
     ... 
 1 << 12  = 4096  // tests bit 13, binary: 0001 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: Thanks - I got the code from the PDF tool vendor so I had to do some digging as to why his code wasn't working.  Once I realized it was off by one everywhere I figured he wasn't taking zero-based into consideration so this was just a sanity check.